# My name is changed for whole network except for stackexchange.com

Tags: support, profile-page, stackexchange.com, network-profile

I have recently changed my name from *Onurcan B.* to *onurcanbektas* in the network, but while changing it, firstly I saved it for only math.SE by mistake and then right away I saved it for the whole community, but when I had checked the other website, my name wasn't changed, so I have entered the "edit profile" menu from physic.SE and changed my name and saved for the whole network and this changed my name for whole network except for the main stackexchange.com.

I have tested if I check the user https://stackexchange.com/users/6687366/onurcanbektas, I redirects me to https://stackexchange.com/users/6687366/onurcan-b, and still the page shows my name as *Onurcan B.*, so how can I solve this problem, and what is the reason for this problem ? Is this bug ?

Comment: Have you clicked on "Update profile info" on the stackexchange site (your second link)?

Comment: As @Tom said, the network profile is not synchronized automatically, you'll have to manually synchronize it with the account of your choice.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I did not know that.Thanks for the info :).